# Why the light in the inside of the room is looking weird when you see it through the window?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, light

This is the window, and in the inside there are two point lights

[image: render]
[image: cycles nodes]

Comment: It is very hard to read you node setup, could please edit your question and provide a bigger picture with better quality.

Comment: The nodes are unreadable. Please edit your question and add an image on a higher resolution

Comment: and, can you at least describe how that light is setup, and how should it look? are those spot lights or what? should they be lights reflected in the window, or?

Comment: I think either you should try play with the light bounces in the render Tab, or it is a strainge placement of your light sources.